# Failed to fetch when using react-doc-viewer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use https://github.com/cyntler/react-doc-viewer to view files in the browser. The problem is that I'm getting `failed to fetch` error for some links. For example, the following src works fine and doc is properly displated:

'https://www.mtsac.edu/webdesign/accessible-docs/word/example03.docx'

but the following doesnt
'https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Free_Test_Data_100KB_XLSX.xlsx' and I m getting an error. What might be the reason and how to fix that?

Comment: are you fetching in the browser? the difference may be CORS

Comment: I dont know what is that but you might be right. I uploaded both files to my DigitalOcean spaces and they both failed. Do I have to set it up on DO? Or in some other way?

Comment: First you need to know [what CORS is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) - then you can make an informed decision for your next step

Comment: Thank you. I followed this https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/how-to/configure-cors/#control-panel i.e. added my domain to the list with get method allowed

but I still get an error. It will not work in develop mode?

Comment: I don't know digital ocean, nor do I know what your code is doing